# C++ and MSVC #define directive with optional arguments

Tags: c++, string, macros, c-preprocessor, directive

I'm having trouble trying to get a macro that I'm writing to function correctly. I've read the docs and can't find anything online to help with what I'm looking for.

I am attempting to write a macro that is used for info and debugging purposes. The exact macro should look like:

```
INFODUMP("Some format string here with a variable %f", someVariableInCode);
```

Which would expand to:

```
std::printf("INFO: Some format string here with a variable %f\n" someVariableInCode);
```

The macro that I have written that doesn't function correctly is:

```
#define INFODUMP(s, ...) std::printf("INFO: %s\n", s, __VA_ARGS__)
```

While technically, this macro is functioning, it doesn't *do* the formatting.

For example, I have:

```
INFODUMP("Size of width buffer: %i, size of height buffer: %i", wCells.size(), hCells.size());
```

And in the console when the program is ran, I get:

```
INFO: Size of width buffer: %i, size of height buffer: %i
```

So the macro *works*, it just isn't formatting the string. It's kind of like formatting it with *s* correctly, but not any of the optional arguments afterwards.

If I had to guess, it has something to do with strings and how they are formatted during runtime. If that's the case, I'm still completely lost on what to look up.

Notes:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community with the Visual C++ (v143) compiler (latest).
- While researching online, the `__VA_OPT__` preprocessor variable isn't a thing anymore, I don't believe, but I could be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `printf()` works.

Your macro expands:

```
INFODUMP("%d", 42);
```

To:

```
std::printf("INFO: %s\n", "%d", 42)
```

You need:

```
 #define INFODUMP(s, ...) std::printf("INFO: " ## s ## "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

Which will then expand:

```
INFODUMP("%d", 42);
```

To:

```
std::printf("INFO: %d\n", 42)
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you so much. However just one small extra question: is there a reason why Visual Studio tells me there is an "Extra argument passed to 'printf'"? I don't see a reason that there would be an extra argument as in my test case there's two %f in the format string and I supplied only 2 variables to the printf. Thanks again

Comment: @QuBitGaming look at the printf statement your macro generated,  it says `printf("%s", x,y)`, you have one % in your format string, but 2 args. You know that that second %d is supposed to mean something, but it doesnt, its just a string to be printed

Comment: @QuBitGaming `INFODUMP("Size of width buffer: %i, size of height buffer: %i", wCells.size(), hCells.size());` would expand to `std::printf("INFO: Size of width buffer: %i, size of height buffer: %i\n", wCells.size(), hCells.size());` which indeed has no extra parameters. But if you had something like `INFODUMP("hi")`, the macro would expand to `std::printf("INFO: hi\n", )` Note the extra `,` in the parameter list...

Comment: @QuBitGaming ... Under standard C/C++, that would be an error, but VC++ suppresses the trailing comma unless `/Zc:preprocessor` is used. What you really want is `std::printf("INFO: hi\n")` instead. There are numerous questions on StackOverflow that explain how to work around this issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau even if you fixed the trailing , its still would complain tho - look at the simple case I show `INFODUMP("%d", 42);` => `std::printf("Info %s\n", "%d", 42)` - there is one % in the format string but 2 args predented

Comment: @pm100 if the OP were using the *original* macro they wrote, yes.  But they are saying they are getting that warning after applying your fix. That warning should not happen in the examples they provided.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using the same toolset and I dont get a warning anymore, I think he was asking why it was present before, OP still doesnt really get why the original didnt work,

Comment: @pm100 "*I think he was asking why it was present before*" - that is not the way I read their comment to your fix. But whatever. Not worth arguing over.